# Filter table rows based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following dataset:

[image]

This specifies cycle of tasks for each facilities, the 'cycleperiod' column specifying start and end date of a cycle,

and the tasks are specified with individual columns specifying startdate and completeion status like so (date~status),

'0' in status means incomplete and '1' means complete.

Now I want to filter rows such that for each facility I get:

1. Current cycle
2. one previous cycle with atleast one task incomplete
3. and one next cycle if next cycle starts withing 3 days of current date

So far i have done this to get current cycle for each facility but cant figure out logic for

```
   select *  from ##finalTempTable1 
   where Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
   and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date);
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please show the original table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on what you are trying to do but here is a starter if i am understanding you correctly:

```
select 
    cycleperiod
from 
    ##finalTempTable1 
where 
    Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
    and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)
    and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
UNION

select 
    max(b.cycleperiod)
from 
    ##finalTempTable1 as a 
    inner join (
        select 
            b.CyclePeriod
        from
            ##finalTempTable1 as b
        WHERE 
            and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
    )as b
        ON Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) < Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) 
where 
    Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
    and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)

UNION

select 
    min(b.cycleperiod)  
from 
    ##finalTempTable1 as a 
    inner join (
        select 
            b.CyclePeriod
        from
            ##finalTempTable1 as b
        WHERE 
            and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
    )as b
        ON Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) > Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) 
where 
    Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
    and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)
    and Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) <= <= dateadd(d,3,getdate() )
```

Basically Union the three sets of data you want together.

to get the next and previous cycleperiods join the table to itself

to get only one result beofre and after you can use max and min as it appears there are no overlapping periods and your dates are formatted such that alphabetical sorting works.

if you want more than just the cycle period column then join this result to the table again, either by using another temp table or like this:

```
select 
    d.*
from 
    ##finalTempTable1  as d
    inner join(
    select 
        cycleperiod
    from 
        ##finalTempTable1 
    where 
        Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
        and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)
        and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
    UNION

    select 
        max(b.cycleperiod)
    from 
        ##finalTempTable1 as a 
        inner join (
            select 
                b.CyclePeriod
            from
                ##finalTempTable1 as b
            WHERE 
                and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
        )as b
            ON Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) < Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) 
    where 
        Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
        and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)

    UNION

    select 
        min(b.cycleperiod)  
    from 
        ##finalTempTable1 as a 
        inner join (
            select 
                b.CyclePeriod
            from
                ##finalTempTable1 as b
            WHERE 
                and right(cycleperiod) = '0'
        )as b
            ON Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) > Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) 
    where 
        Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) >=   cast(getdate() as date)
        and cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CyclePeriod, CHARINDEX(''o'',CyclePeriod,0) + 2, 11))) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date)
        and Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.CyclePeriod, 0, 11))) as date) <= <= dateadd(d,3,getdate() )
    ) as c
        on d.cycleperiod = c.CyclePeriod
```